# Need to show pure PHP validation errors on Form Page

Tags: php

I have a form.php script that gets Name, Email and Message through HTML and inserts it into DB, no problem.

However, I would like for it to show a simple error, such as 'You did not inform your whatever' if the user fails to fill any field.

My form has action="actions.php" where data is validated and passed to DB and then redirects back to form.php so the user never actually sees anything there.

Is there any way I can make my code show the mentioned error only if a field is left blank with just PHP?

I have tried **if $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] && empty($_POST["name"]) then $err = "Please inform blablabla";** in actions.php and also in form.php. It just didn't work in form.php because the form got sent to actions.php anyway.

And, if I require actions.php in form.php, I get the 'too many redirects' error. I actually need to access the $nameErr variable in form.php.

I know I could process everything in actions.php and show any data there, but I regard it as a bad user experience since he will need to manually go back to form.php in order to re-enter data.

Here is the code: **form.php**

```
<form class="center-div" method="post" action="actions.php">

<div class="field margin-bottom-small">Name</div> 
<input style="outline: none;" class="margin-bottom-small" type="text" name="name">
<span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;  ?></span> <!-- Error here -->

<div class="field margin-bottom-small">Email</div> 
<input style="outline: none;" class="margin-bottom-small" type="text" name="email">

<div class="field margin-bottom-small">Message</div> 
<textarea style="outline: none;" class="margin-bottom-small" name="message" rows="5" columns="40"></textarea>

<input class="submit-button margin-bottom-small" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

**Actions.php**: test_input is just a function I use to sanitize input data.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Please inform your name"; // my blank field error. 
    header("Location: form.php");
    // exit; 
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }


  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {

  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }


  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {

  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it do if you un-comment the exit just below where you set your header?

Comment: Store the error data in the session or pass it as querystring parameters.

Comment: You could use the required attribute for your form fields in the HTML